# Migrator.Net - create from existing database

Tags: .net, data-migration

We are thinking of starting to use Migrator.Net and I was wondering if there is any way of creating/importing the existing schemas and creating the class files. It would be a lot of work to create them all by hand, but in all my searching I can't seem to find anything that will do this.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the project doesn't seem to be mantained anymore ( http://www.mail-archive.com/migratordotnet-devel@googlegroups.com/msg00482.html ).

There's no reverse engineering option, although what one of devs soundly suggested was to use regular sql snapshots on a major version changes:

> one approach to migrations is, that the use of migrations isn't forever, you
>   develop your database and it evolves with the help of migrations, but once
>   in a long time (major version?)
>   you flush everything down into a sql-create script, and create a new blank
>   migration assembly to start off with, so you might want to use that approach
>   either way.

( http://www.mail-archive.com/migratordotnet-devel@googlegroups.com/msg00190.html )